# Multiple inner joins with different where-conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

I am currently using the following query to perform a search across multiple tables via INNER JOIN.

```
    SELECT title, m2.txt1 AS teaser, inputdat, db_file.*
       FROM db_item 
            INNER JOIN db_itemv AS m1 USING(id_item) 
            INNER JOIN db_itemf USING(id_item) 
            INNER JOIN db_itemd USING(id_item) 
            INNER JOIN db_itemv AS m2 USING(id_item)
       WHERE type=15 AND m1.fldnr='12' 
AND m1.indik='b' AND m1.txt1s='en'
 AND visibility=0 AND inputdat>'2005-11-02' AND m2.fldnr='123'
       GROUP BY title
       ORDER BY inputdat DESC
       LIMIT 0,100
```

The columns of db_itemv (m1, m2) are named:

```
ID   id_item   fldnr   indik   txt1
```

One id_item may exist on several rows.

My problem is, that m2.fldnr='123' does not always exist and therefore it kicks out the whole row. But I want to keep the row and keep the column empty when it doesn't exist in the row. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a couple of issues here, so bear with me whilst I go through them :)

I agree with @Jeurgen that you need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`, which will enable you to retrieve all the rows that you are searching for, including those without an entry in `m2`.

However, as your where clause specifically states only give me that data which DOES HAVE an `m2.fldnr` value equal to '123', then it is correct for you not to have any rows which do not having matching `m2` rows, as they cannot meet your criteria.

I think what you are trying to do is pull all data from the first four tables, and then only data within the `m2` table that contains '123', if this is the case, then you need to relocate your `m2.fldnr` filter, and handle those missing rows...

My version of your query is thus as follows - this has not been tested, as I don't have sample data with your structure, but give it a try, and vary it if needed;

```
SELECT title, m2.txt1 AS teaser, inputdat, db_file.*
FROM db_item 
    INNER JOIN db_itemv AS m1 USING(id_item) 
    INNER JOIN db_itemf USING(id_item) 
    INNER JOIN db_itemd USING(id_item) 
    LEFT JOIN  db_itemv AS m2 
      ON db_item.id_item = m2.id_item
      AND ( m2.fldnr = '123' OR m2.fldnr IS NULL )
WHERE type=15 
    AND m1.fldnr = '12' 
    AND m1.indik = 'b'
    AND m1.txt1s = 'en'
    AND visibility = 0 
    AND inputdat > '2005-11-02' 
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY inputdat DESC
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much for the neat explanation and the query :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace all `inner join`  with `left outer join`

Comment: Seems not to solve the problem for me. When I perform the whole query without the last join and thus the last WHERE condition the result count is quite different. Do you have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `LEFT JOIN` instead `INNER JOIN db_itemv AS m2`
which should return all other data even when `db_itemv` returns NULL.